# Reference for the fact: elements as union of atoms in a Atomic Boolean lattice

Tags: reference-request, logic, boolean-algebra

I need a reference to a book with the following statement: "In a Atomic Boolean Lattice every element is the union of the atoms under lie it". Does not matter if it is presented as a exercise.

Answer (score 1):

See :

- Steven Givant & Paul Halmos, [Introduction to Boolean algebras](https://books.google.it/books?id=ORILyf8sF2sC&pg=PA118) (2009), page 118 :

> **Lemma 3** [Tarski]. The following conditions on a Boolean algebra are equivalent.
>
> > (1) The algebra is atomic.
> >
> > (2) Every element is the supremum of the atoms it dominates.
> >
> > (3) The unit is the supremum of the set of all atoms.